# Get Distinct From Multiple Similar Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query to join a couple tables and get distinct values, it looks something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [TrackingCode]
    ,[Opponent]
    ,CONCAT([TrackingCode], ' | ', [Opponent]) AS RowName
    ,[MultiYrEvent] 
    ,[Identifier]
FROM [BUDGET_FY2014].[dbo].[TrackingCodes]

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM [BUDGET_FY2014].[dbo].[Transactions]
    WHERE Report='2377010003'
) AS T
ON T.EventCode LIKE CAST(TrackingCodes.TrackingCode AS nvarchar(20))+'%'
ORDER BY TrackingCode ASC
```

It works fine. However, I've got multiple Transactions tables with the same schema for the first and second previous years relative to the Transactions table, and I'd like to see distinct values from all three tables. So for example, if I copy/paste this query and change `[Transactions]` to `[Transactions_Yr1]` or `[Transactions_Yr2]`, then I get the data I want from those tables. But, I want to combine the three. If I try to join them all, I  get no results returned. I *sort of* understand why this doesn't work, but I don't know where to go from here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [TrackingCode]
    ,[Opponent]
    ,CONCAT([TrackingCode], ' | ', [Opponent]) AS RowName
    ,[MultiYrEvent] 
    ,[Identifier]
FROM [BUDGET_FY2014].[dbo].[TrackingCodes]

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM [BUDGET_FY2014].[dbo].[Transactions]
    WHERE Report='2377010003'
) AS T
ON T.EventCode LIKE CAST(TrackingCodes.TrackingCode AS nvarchar(20))+'%'

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM [BUDGET_FY2014].[dbo].[Transactions_Yr1]
    WHERE Report='2377010003'
) AS T1
ON T1.EventCode LIKE CAST(TrackingCodes.TrackingCode AS nvarchar(20))+'%'

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM [BUDGET_FY2014].[dbo].[Transactions_Yr2]
    WHERE Report='2377010003'
) AS T2
ON T2.EventCode LIKE CAST(TrackingCodes.TrackingCode AS nvarchar(20))+'%'

ORDER BY TrackingCode ASC
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it because you're doing INNER JOINS and there are event codes missing in one or more of the tables?    Try LEFT OUTER JOINs and see what you get.

Comment: An inner join (or a join in general) is conceptually about combining tables in the horizontal direction usually by matching up common values inside their rows. Unions (which is what you want) are a different kind of combining that works in the vertical direction and just stacks the tables together (along with an option to remove duplicate rows.)

Comment: @shawnt00 thanks for the concise explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try use UNION ALL clausele, e.g.:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT [FILDS] 
 FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM [BUDGET_FY2014].[dbo].[Transactions]
    WHERE Report='2377010003'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT * 
    FROM [BUDGET_FY2014].[dbo].[Transactions_Yr1]
    WHERE Report='2377010003'

    UNION ALL

     SELECT * 
    FROM [BUDGET_FY2014].[dbo].[Transactions_Yr2]
    WHERE Report='2377010003'
    )

ORDER BY TrackingCode ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried unioning your transaction tables together? 
Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

```
SELECT DISTINCT [TrackingCode]
    ,[Opponent]
    ,CONCAT([TrackingCode], ' | ', [Opponent]) AS RowName
    ,[MultiYrEvent] 
    ,[Identifier]
FROM [BUDGET_FY2014].[dbo].[TrackingCodes]

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT * 
    FROM [BUDGET_FY2014].[dbo].[Transactions]
    WHERE Report='2377010003'
) AS T
ON T.EventCode LIKE CAST(TrackingCodes.TrackingCode AS nvarchar(20))+'%'

Union
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM [BUDGET_FY2014].[dbo].[Transactions_Yr1]
    WHERE Report='2377010003'
) AS T1
ON T1.EventCode LIKE CAST(TrackingCodes.TrackingCode AS nvarchar(20))+'%'

Union
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM [BUDGET_FY2014].[dbo].[Transactions_Yr2]
    WHERE Report='2377010003'
) AS T2
ON T2.EventCode LIKE CAST(TrackingCodes.TrackingCode AS nvarchar(20))+'%'
)
ORDER BY TrackingCode ASC
```

Comment: Unions was the answer, but it was simpler to union them together inside the join